# Remove duplicate rows #2

Tags: sql, sqlite, duplicates, distinct

I have a (large ~1 000 000 rows) table that potentially contains duplicate rows (possible NULL values).

What I want to do is this:

1. Select only distinc rows.
2. Remove rows with duplicate 'id' field.

Let's have a table:

```
id | a | b    
1  | 2 | 3    
2  | 8 | 7    
3  | 9 | 10    
2  | 8 | 7    
3  | 20| 12
```

What I want to get is:

```
id | a | b    
1  | 2 | 3    
2  | 8 | 7
```

Row with id 2 is preserved in one copy, while rows with id 3 were removed.

I was thinking about:

1. `SELECT DISTINCT id, a, b FROM table`; to get only distinct rows.
2. Somehow filter the result of (1) to remove duplicate ids.

What would be the best way to approach this?

Comment: I'm curious as to what you found when you entered `sql remove duplicate rows` into the SO search box. Did you get the forty pages of results that I did? :-) Sorry, couldn't resist the jab: see http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+remove+duplicate+rows

Comment: Row 2 is repeated twice and it's listed below, yet row 1 is not repeated twice and it's listed below as well.  That's a little confusing, I assume you meant to have only row 1 below, or perhaps row 1 and row 3?

Comment: @Neil, I think `2` survived because the contents were identical. `3` was tossed since the two records were different (in other words, keep one copy of an id if all copies are identical, otherwise toss it out), which probably makes my smarmy comment above inaccurate since this seems to be a fairly special case :-) Apologies to Petr if that _is_ the case.

Comment: @paxdiablo Then why is `1` there?

Comment: @paxdiablo Yes. That is exactly what I want. Identical rows survive, but rows with duplicate ID and distinct other fields are removed.

Comment: @paxdiablo I should mention that unique rows (like id 1) survive automatically.

Comment: @Neil, I read it as `1` will combine the two ID=2 records because they're _not_ distinct. Then, there's only one copy of ID=1 and ID=2 so they're left in, but two of ID=3, hence it gets turfed out. But, having decoded the question, I think it's beyond my meagre SQL skills so I'll bow out. Best of luck with an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Petr, it looks like per the comments, you want a COMBINATION...

Include:
   All rows where the ID occurs ONLY ONCE
   All rows where the ID occurs MORE than once -- AND all the other fields on the record are the same

EXCLUDE:
   Any row where the ID occurs more than once -- AND the other fields do not exactly match.

```
select ID, min(a) a, min(b) b
    from YourTable
    group by ID
    having min(a) = max(a)
       and min(b) = max(b)
```

If you have more columns aside from a and b to compare, just add the respective values to the select field list and the corresponding having. From the data sample you've provided, the values return from the query would be

```
ID  MIN(A)  MIN(B)    Having MIN(A)  MAX(A)  MIN(B)  MAX(B)
1    2        3                2        2       3      3 
2    8        7                8        8       7      7
3    9       10                9       20      10     12
```

So the row ID = 3 will get tossed since the having will fail on a same min() and max() of the same column across BOTH columns.  Then, you can copy this into a new table.  Only one pass through the table...

Answer (score 2):

Third Answer now that the question is slightly clearer:

```
SELECT id, min(a) as a, min(b) as b
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT id, a, b FROM table) t
GROUP BY id
HAVING count(*) =1
```

Comment: The problem is that the table must contain all rows. Filtering must be done while selecting data...

Comment: @Petr Your question says: '2. Remove rows with duplicate 'id' field.'  Which is confusing.

Comment: I meant "remove from SELECT results", not from the table itself. Sorry.

Comment: @Petr, I have updated my answer, but "remove from SELECT results" is a strange way to say "SELECT fewer rows".

Answer (score 0):

Can you rebuild the database, or if not build a new one from the original, with id as a primary key? SQL can take care of the rest.

Comment: This should go in comment not in answer ;-)